# How to use color dodge blending in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using SpriteKit and I want to achieve a Photoshop like color blending mode "dodge color" of a node in the foreground with other nodes and the background. My first approach was to use a SKEffectNode using a CIColorDodgeBlendMode filter. Unfortunately this filter needs a background image as parameter. I did not get this construction working.

My second though then was to use the SKShader class. But there seems to be no way to access the framebuffer (or the actual pixel data from the background to combine the color with).

So long story short: is there a way to have a dodge color effect in SpriteKit with the SKEffectNode - or to access the background pixels in a SpriteKit shader program?

Thanks for your time and help :)

Addition: for the Shader program, I want to achieve what is mentioned in [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW23) under "Fetch Framebuffer Data for Programmable Blending"